# Android SDK won't install without JDK

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, sdk

Ok, so I'm having trouble installing my Android SDK on my Macbook Pro 2012 64bit  running Bootcamp.
I installed the new JDK 1.8 and its located in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\"
(I installed the 64 bit version becuase i did not see 32 bit.)

I try to install the SDK but it says i have to create an environmental variable to the path java.exe path b/c the JDK was not found.
So i did. My system variable ,JAVA_HOME's, path was created to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\"
I also tried "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe" and "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\" and still no luck.

The same error message still occurs.

I also looked up this question before I typed this but all the answers gave me no luck. My main goal is to work on Android development with IntelliJ, so far I can create Java program with ease but with the SDK installing I can't work on my Android develpment, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you exactly try before? Did you try to press **back**, when the error message appeared, and then again **next** ?

Comment: i tried that, i exited out of the installer multiple times and tried different paths for variable, I uninstalled and re installed the JDK and still no luck, I probably tried 10-15 times already and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, First i had to set my JAVA_HOME as a user variable next i had to change the backslashes into forward slashes like this "C:/program files/java/jdk1.8.0_05" it's stupid but yea

Comment: I'm impressed that it works. Usually one has to put Java in a path with no spaces or use its ~PROGRA1 alias. Also, \\ might work as well as / separators.